# Which approach to use to download many images asynchronously

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've a `ListView` in which each row item contains many `ImageViews` apart from some content.

That is, there will be many list items, each containing many images.

In order to not to hold user unnecessarily, I'm showing the content first & then downloading the images asynchronously.

Currently, for each image I'm starting a new `AsycTask`.
Although, it working alright, but this not a good approach.

In place of this, what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

use this library, best in android for image loading..
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario seems to fit exactly to use `LazyLoading` of images. This basically loads images in the background and shows them as soon as they're loaded.

You might want to see this:

- [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

An alternative would be using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the images to load, but the above works pretty well and is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the library 
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Many common pitfalls of image loading on Android are handled automatically by Picasso:

Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
Automatic memory and disk caching.